# SQLite - SELECT DISTINCT of one column and get the others

Tags: sqlite

This has been touched on before on this website. I want distinct on group but I also want to get the other fields too. what I need is the lowest id of each group, but instead I get the highest. I've tried variod SQL queries and the nearest 2 that work are

1)

```
select * 
from reminder 
group by Eventgroup 
order by autoid
```

2)

```
SELECT distinct Autoid,EventDate,Subject,birthdate,Eventgroup 
from reminder 
group by Eventgroup 
order by autoid
```

Data:

```
EventDate    Subject          birthdate       Eventgroup    autoid

09/10/2017   Joes Birthday     09/10/1995      4            9
13/07/2017   Bill Birthday     13/07/1999      2            8
04/04/2017   Tony Birthday     04/04/1993      3            7
09/10/2016   Joes Birthday     09/10/1995      4            6
13/07/2016   Bill Birthday     13/07/1999      2            5
04/04/2016   Tony Birthday     04/04/1993      3            4
09/10/2015   Joes Birthday     09/10/1995      4            3
13/07/2015   Bill Birthday     13/07/1999      2            2
04/04/2015   Tony Birthday     04/04/1993      3            1
```

both of these queries return

```
09/10/2017   Joes Birthday     09/10/1995      4            9
13/07/2017   Bill Birthday     13/07/1999      2            8
04/04/2017   Tony Birthday     04/04/1993      3            7
```

what I want is the earliets dates such as

```
09/10/2015   Joes Birthday     09/10/1995      4            3
13/07/2015   Bill Birthday     13/07/1999      2            2
04/04/2015   Tony Birthday     04/04/1993      3            1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: I did have a look at this but I couldn't get it to work with SQLLite

Comment: Not sure why you couldn't get it to work. See my answer, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with a subquery that finds the earliest date for each event group.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM reminders a
JOIN (SELECT eventgroup, MIN(eventdate) mindate
      FROM reminders
      GROUP BY eventgroup) b
ON a.eventgroup = b.eventgroup AND a.eventdate = b.mindate
```

This is the same structure as the second query in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800572/1491895) in the duplicate question.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/71bac2/1)